# Formulate an analogue of Prop. 3.12 for angles.

Tags: geometry

The proposition 3.12 is : Given AC is congruent to DF, then for any point B between A and C, there is a unique point E between D and F such that AB is congruent to DE.

The following is my analogue of it by angles:

Given angle ABC is congruent to angle PQR, then for every angle ABD less than ABC, there is a unique angle PQS less than PQR such that angle ABD is congruent to angle PQS.

I don't know if it is correct. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I'm not sure you can easily "imply" the points $D$ and $S$ like that. You might have to constrain them to the respective lines, so for any point $D$ on $AC$ there is a unique point $S$ on $PR$ such that $\angle ABD \cong \angle PQS$

Comment: I need it for angles, not lines. Since the original proposition is about lines, my new proposition should be about angles.

Comment: And indeed I'm talking about angles. But generally you need three points to talk about an angle.

Comment: Yes, I do have three points for every angle. Oh, I know what you mean. But the points D and S should be interior to angle ABC and angle PQR, that's why I said angle ABD is less than ABC and angle PQS is less than than PQR. If they are on lines, both of them should be equal. You misunderstand the question.

Comment: No, I don't misunderstand the question. I'm disputing that you can specify an angle without specifying a point *first*, and giving you a way to specify that point.

Comment: I got you. Thanks!